# Why doesn't Sequence@@ work inside Manipulate[]?

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, sequence

I'm trying to use `Manipulate[]` and I need to have a non-fixed amount of sliders.

I tried writing something like:

```
Manipulate[x,Sequence@@{{x,0,1},{y,0,1}}]
```

**I wrote only two parameters in this example, but I want a solution that works for an unknown amount of parameters.**

If I learned this correctly, the Sequence head should "fall off" and the expression should become:

```
Manipulate[x,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

as it does in the case of:

```
f[Sequence@@{{x,0,1},{y,0,1}}]==f[{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

but it doesn't. Instead, I get the following error:

```
Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument Sequence@@{{x,0,1},{y,0,1}} does not have the correct form for a variable specification.
```

Why doesn't it work?

I've seen the docs page of `Sequence[]` and I know that functions with either the `SequenceHold` or the `HoldAllComplete` attributes do not splice automatically, but `Attributes[Manipulate]` shows me that Manipulate doesn't have either of those.

Does it have to do with `Manipulate[]` having the `ReadProtected` attribute?

I also know `Dynamic[]` should do the trick, but I don't really want to learn about it (even thought I probably will, eventually)

Thanks

Comment: The `Head` of `Sequence @@ {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}` is `Apply`. So the `HoldAll` attribute of `Manipulate` keeps it from applying `Sequence` to the list. You could use `Evaluate[Sequence @@ {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}]`, perhaps, but `x` and `y` will be evaluated.

Comment: This may be a good alternative: `Manipulate[x, ##] & @@ Hold[{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`. Probably depends on your actual use-case.  You could also use `Hold[{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] /. Hold[i1_, i2_] :> Manipulate[x, i1, i2]`, which can be more flexible. For instance `Hold[{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] /. Hold[i1__] :> Manipulate[x, i1]`, where now `i1` represents all sliders.

Comment: Or `Manipulate @@ {x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}}`

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Manipulate[x, ##] & @@ Hold[{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` worked, thanks. Maybe it wasn't clear but I want this to work for a variable amount of parameters, and it does.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, that also works, even though I don't fancy the idea of writing all the arguments to `Manipulate` in a separate list and only then applying it.

Comment: If you have more than two variables, `Manipulate @@ {f @@ (x /@ Range[10]), Sequence @@ ({{x[#], 0, Subscript["x", #]}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[10])}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you build your Manipulate up out of pre-computed components rather than try to one-line it. Something like this:

```
With[
  {controls = Sequence[{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
   body = {x, y, Sin[x] Cos[y]}},
  Manipulate[
    body,
    controls]]
```

As for your requirement that it works for an unknown number of parameters, that's still doable, but you need to get creative in how you create the symbols associated to each control.

```
MyManipulate[n_] :=
  With[
    {symbols = Symbol[StringJoin["x" <> ToString[#]]] & /@ Range@n},
    With[
      {controls = Sequence @@ Table[{sym, 0, 1}, {sym, symbols}],
       body = symbols},
      Manipulate[
        body,
        controls]]]
```

Of course, I don't know how things work in your actual context, so this probably won't work directly--it's just a demo.